# Using return redirect() cause Error 'Return value must be of type string' in CodeIgniter 4 validation process

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **Codeigniter 4 v4.3.4**. I tried using **form validation** to validate my form and try to redirect if the form does not pass the validation process. Here is my code :

```
if ( $this->request->getPost() )
{
    if ( ! $this->validate([
        'fullName' => [
            'rules'         => 'required',
        ],
        'nickName' => [
            'rules'         => 'required',
        ],
        'gender' => [
            'rules'         => 'required',
        ],
        'profile' => [
            'rules'         => 'required',
        ]
    ]) )
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
}
```

But I got an error message:
`Return value must be of type string, CodeIgniter\HTTP\RedirectResponse returned`

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Does anyone have advice on how to fix this?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You're returning an instance of `RedirectResonse`-class, while the method/function has a string as return type. You've missed adding the function/method definition to the question. If it can return different types, you need to [add those as well.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Ok  I understand what is wrong with my code. As of PHP 8.2 method/function automatically declare ReturnType and I am using String. Simply remove my ReturnType and everything working as expected. Thank you for pointing me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I already solved it by removing the :string

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You have a type declaration on your method. Your controller method may look something like this:

```
    public function myMethod(): string
    {
        helper('form');

        $model = model(PostsModel::class);

        $data = [
            'posts' => $model->getPosts(),
            'title' => "The Page Title"
        ];
        // IDK... some more stuff for some reason...

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

You are forcing a return type with the `: string`, which is in many cases a good thing for debugging. You kept getting errors, while developing, right away, right?
Better than just removing `: string`, which would make your code look like this:

```
    public function myMethod() 
        // ^ look... no ": string's" attached! sorry...
    {  
        // your code...

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

add `: RedirectResponse | string` so that your code looks more like this:

```
    public function myMethod(): RedirectResponse | string
    {
        
       // The things you're doing and stuff...

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

or declare any return type you are expecting, separated by a pipe. This allows you to redirect on one condition and return a view in another condition.